# How to find all possible pairs from three subsets of a set with constraints in Erlang?

Tags: set, erlang, subset

I have a set M which consists of three subsets A,B and C.

*Problem:* I would like to calculate all possible subsets S(1)...S(N) of M which contain all possible pairs between elements of A, B and C in such manner that:

1. elements of A and B can happen in a pair only once for each of two positions in a pair (that is `{a1,a2}` and `{b1,a1}` can be in one subset S, but no more elements `{a1,_} and {_,a1}` are allowed in this subset S);
2. elements of C can happen 1-N times in a subset S (that is `{a,c}, {b,c}, {x,c}` can happen in one subset S), but I would like to get subsets S for all possible numbers of elements of C in a subset S.

For example, if we have `A = [a1,a2], B = [b1,b2], C = [c1,c2]`, then some of the resulting subsets S would be (remember, they should contain pairs of elements):

```
- {a1,b1}, {b1,a2}, {a2,b2}, {b2,c1};
- {a1,b1}, {b1,a2}, {a2,b2}, {b2,c1}, {c1,c2};
- {a1,c1}, {c1,a2}, {c1,b2}, {b1,c1};
- etc.
```

I tend to think that first I need to find all possible subsets of M, which contain only one element of A, one element of B and 1..N elements of C `(1)`. And after that I should somehow generate sets of pairs `(2)` from that. But I am not sure that this is the right strategy.

So, the more elaborated question would be:

- what is the best way to create sets and find subsets in Erlang if the elements of the set M a integers?
- are there any ready-made tools to find subsets of a set in Erlang?
- are there any ready-made tools to generate all possible pairs of elements of a set in Erlang?
- How can I solve the aforementioned problem in Erlang?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`sets` module*](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sets.html), but I suspect you're better off thinking up an *algorithm* first -- its implementation in Erlang is the problem (or not) that comes after this.  (Maybe you notice its actually a [graph algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_algorithm#Graph_algorithms) (like, bipartite matching something something), and you'll get happy [with Erlang's `digraph` module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html).)

Long story short, when you come up with an algorithm, Erlang can very probably be used to implement it.  Yes, there is a certain support for sets.  But solutions to a problem requiring "all possible subsets" tend to be exponential (i.e., given `n` elements, there are `2^n` subsets; for every element you either have it in your subset or not) and thus bad.

[(* there are some modules concerning sets)](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-March/050318.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about 2^n subsets. The described problem probably cannot be solved with a graph algorithm (thus I have asked the question).

Comment: Since the power set is a set of sets, the [`sofs`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sofs.html) module might helpful, too, while being rather mathematical. [Look here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Erlang) for a list-based algorithm for constructing the power set in Erlang.  (From here you could use `sets`' `from_list` and probably `fold` to iterate over all subsets.)