# How can I find all 'long' simple acyclic paths in a graph?

Tags: graph, path, traversal, directed-graph, powerset

Let's say we have a fully connected directed graph `G`. The vertices are `[a,b,c]`. There are edges in both directions between each vertex.

Given a starting vertex `a`, I would like to traverse the graph in all directions and save the path only when I hit a vertex which is already in the path.

So, the function `full_paths(a,G)` should return:

```
- [{a,b}, {b,c}, {c,d}]
- [{a,b}, {b,d}, {d,c}]
- [{a,c}, {c,b}, {b,d}]
- [{a,c}, {c,d}, {d,b}]
- [{a,d}, {d,c}, {c,b}]
- [{a,d}, {d,b}, {b,c}]
```

I do not need 'incomplete' results like `[{a,b}]` or `[{a,b}, {b,c}]`, because it is contained in the first result already.

Is there any other way to do it except of generating a powerset of G and filtering out results of certain size?

How can I calculate this?

**Edit**: As Ethan pointed out, this could be solved with depth-first search method, but unfortunately I do not understand how to modify it, making it store a path before it backtracks (I use Ruby [Gratr](http://rubydoc.info/gems/gratr/0.4.3/GRATR/Graph/Search#dfs-instance_method) to implement my algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or some variation? A depth first search traverses as far as possible and then backtracks. You can record the path each time you need to backtrack.

Comment: Ethan, I thought about dfs, but I don't get how I can exactly record each path.

Comment: Look at the callback options and the example given in the [documentation for bfs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/gratr/0.4.3/GRATR/Graph/Search:bfs). You can use the callbacks to keep track of the edges traversed and the vertexes visited to keep track of each path.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your graph **`G`** is fully connected there is `N!` paths of length `N` when `N` is number of vertices in graph **`G`**. You can easily compute it in this way. You have `N` possibilities of choice starting point, then for each starting point you can choose `N-1` vertices as second vertex on a path and so on when you can chose only last not visited vertex on each path. So you have `N*(N-1)*...*2*1 = N!` possible paths. When you can't chose starting point i.e. it is given it is same as finding paths in graph **`G'`** with `N-1` vertices. All possible paths are permutation of set of all vertices i.e. in your case all vertices except starting point. When you have permutation you can generate path by:

```
perm_to_path([A|[B|_]=T]) -> [{A,B}|perm_to_path(T)];
perm_to_path(_) -> [].
```

simplest way how to generate permutations is

```
permutations([]) -> [];
permutations(L) ->
  [[H|T] || H <- L, T <- permutations(L--[H])].
```

So in your case:

```
paths(A, GV) -> [perm_to_path([A|P]) || P <- permutations(GV--[A])].
```

where `GV` is list of vertices of graph **`G`**.

If you would like more efficient version it would need little bit more trickery.